# Storage: on change event

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime

I'm still new to the WinRT world and working for the first time with roaming settings. At different points in my project I write or read the settings. So I'm wondering if there's a way to get notified whenever a specific value of my settings is changed. There seems to be the [DataChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.datachanged.aspx) event, but I think it refers to incoming setting changes from the cloud and is therefore not appropriate?!

Comment: I'm not following, because if DataChanged (for which your assessment is correct) isn't appropriate for your needs, where are the changes coming from?  If from within your app, you're controlling when the settings are changed in your own code so could wrap your reads/writes to settings with essentially a repository pattern and include whatever notification, logging, etc. there.

Comment: Ok, that's what I figured out later yesterday as well. In the first place I thought there might be some built-in stuff that makes it easier. I'll have a look at some patterns. Thanks anyway!